# Inflating layout in adapter ignores size

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to inflate this resource in a listadapter:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_micro" >

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#00ff00"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

using the following code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.myview, parent, false);
    }

    return view;
}
```

Though I'm specifying the root of `myview` with height and width of 200dp, it completely ignores the size, and results in size of 0x0.

Specifying custom height and width in code results in the view taking the size of the parent, again ignoring my `200dp` preference:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = dpToPx(200);
layoutParams.width = dpToPx(200);
view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

How can I achieve what I want, having the root of the `View` at 200x200dp and it's children with a relative size to `match_parent`?

Comment: Try to wrap your FrameLayout with some parent layout which has layout_width and layout_height attributes specified to match_parent. Then inside that parent you can set size and gravity of your FrameLayout

Comment: Ah, that works! Any idea on why this root size is ignored?

Comment: i think it is because you are inflating layout without attaching to root, but not sure http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean)

Comment: Hmm, okay. In a `ListAdapter` you shouldn't attach to root, this is done for you afterwards. A bit odd behavior if you ask me.

Comment: Maybe layout params are ignored completely in such case. Use suggested workaround if it is appropriate

Comment: It is. If you could add this as an answer I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap your FrameLayout with some parent layout which has layout_width and layout_height attributes specified to match_parent. Then inside that parent you can set size and gravity of your FrameLayout –

Answer (score 1):

Basically, add another layout and specify the height to that layout. When working with adapter views specifying a height for the root layout doesn't work.